# Which one is correct? Wages Vs wage

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In order to distinguish plural nouns from singular nouns I want to know which one is correct:

> Julia complains that her wage is low.

or

> Julia complains that her wages are low.

I've seen both in texts some people use `wages` as singular (wage) noun and some people use it as plural noun (wages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, Julia is complaining about her wage (or hourly) rate, which is singular.

In the second case, Julia is complaining about all of the money she is earning at her job, which is plural.

Comment: So both are correct?

Comment: Yes, both sentences are correct but have slightly different but related meanings. If her wage rate (singular) is low that will affect the total money she earns, and if her total wages (plural) are low that implies her rate is also low (or possibly she works too few hours).

Comment: !  You're right, as I see in [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wages). And according to Webster 'wages" is more often.